# getting credits payment informations via graph. is user id encoded?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, credits

i was getting user id via graph.
i was using adress like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/9006063926101?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

now this adress giving me a source like this:

{"id":"9006063926101","from":"**_eYRh7mSoymzsd_wsJKF6UJOV5E**","to":"**_eYRh7mSoymzsd_wsJKF6UJOV5E**","amount":40,"status":"settled","application":{"name":"Kapitalizm","canvas_name":"yildizalimi","namespace":"yildizalimi","id":"xxxxxxxxx"},"country":"TR","created_time":"2011-11-03T06:38:01+0000","updated_time":"2011-11-03T06:38:09+0000"}

please pay attention to bold part of this source. till today i was see user id which made payment for my app. what i am seeing now? how can i parse user id from this?